# PHP - Sum of array values based on key

Tags: php, arrays

Below is the array output which shows user data, month wise. I need to get the sum of `ACTUAL_HOURS` for different resources.

For below, sum of ACTUAL_HOURS for `User 1 and User 2` for the month `JUL-2015`, should be `10 + 20 = 30`. 
Same goes for `AUG-2015` which is `80 + 20 = 100`

`$user_array` output

```
Array
(
    [User 1] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 10
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 20
                )

            [AUG-2015] => Array
                (
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 80
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 88
                )

        )

    [User 2] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 20
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 0
                )

            [AUG-2015] => Array
                (
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 20 
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 0
                )

        )
)
```

`$project_months` output

```
Array
(
    [0] => JUL-2015
    [1] => AUG-2015
)
```

Looping the data like below gives summation but not for `User 1`

```
foreach ($user_array as $user_name => $user_data) {

    foreach ($project_months as $month) {
   }
}
```

How do I show summation of `ACTUAL_HOURS` or `PROJECTED_HOURS` for different resource month wise as shown above ?

Comment: Why don't you calculate all these in db? (If you keep data in db of course.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use two foreach loops.

```
$hoursInMonth = array();
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    foreach ($user as $month => $userData) {
        $hoursInMonth[$month] += $userData['ACTUAL_HOURS'];
    }
}
```

Considering the `$users` variable is the array from the question, this yields the following result:

```
Array
(
    [JUL-2015] => 30
    [AUG-2015] => 100
)
```

You could wrap it in a function, so you can easily switch between the desired index.

```
/**
 * @param array $inputArray The input array
 * @param string $typeOfHours The desired index
 * @return array
 */
function calculateHoursInMonths(array $inputArray, $typeOfHours)
{
    $hoursInMonth = array();

    foreach ($inputArray as $user)
    {
        foreach ($user as $month => $userData) {
            $hoursInMonth[$month] += $userData[$typeOfHours];
        }
    }

    return $hoursInMonth;
}
```

Note, this does not take in consideration the Offshore/Onshore state. You can add that by adding a simple `if`.

Comment: Will this calculate for `JUL-2015`, Offshore/Onsite has how many actual or projected hours i.e.differential onsite and offshore hours ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy I added more code and an output for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. There is no need for two nested foreach loops. You just need a for loop to loop through project months and a foreach loop to loop through users array.

You did not shared the array in php code, but I assume you are array is as below:

```
$array  = array(
    'User 1' => array(
        'JUL-2015' => array(
                'SITES_STATUS' => 'Offshore',
                'ACTUAL_HOURS' => 10,
                'PROJECTED_HOURS' => 20
            ),
        'AUG-2015' => array(
                'SITES_STATUS' => 'Offshore',
                'ACTUAL_HOURS' => 80,
                'PROJECTED_HOURS' => 88
            ),

        ),
    'User 2' => array(
        'JUL-2015' => array(
                'SITES_STATUS' => 'Offshore',
                'ACTUAL_HOURS' => 20,
                'PROJECTED_HOURS' => 0
            ),
        'AUG-2015' => array(
                'SITES_STATUS' => 'Offshore',
                'ACTUAL_HOURS' => 20,
                'PROJECTED_HOURS' => 0
            ),

        ),
);
```

And months are below:

```
$project_months = array('JUL-2015', 'AUG-2015');
```

Now to calculate total actual hours for all users for each month, you will need loops like below:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($project_months); $i++) { 
    $totalActualHours = 0;
    foreach($array AS $ar) {
        $totalActualHours += $ar[$project_months[$i]]['ACTUAL_HOURS'];
    }
    echo $project_months[$i].': '.$totalActualHours.'<br>';     
}
```

The output of this code when run for `ACTUAL_HOURS`:

```
JUL-2015: 30
AUG-2015: 100
```

Hope this will help.